# Find the conditions which guarantee a polyhedron is bounded (i.e., a polytope)?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

Note, a polyhedron is the intersection of finitely many half spaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a polytope is a bounded polyhedron.

**Preliminary:** Consider a hyperplane $C_1x_1 + C_2x_2 + \dots + C_nx_n + D = 0$ not passing through the origin. Since not passing through the origin, the term $D \ne 0$ and then both equation sides can be divided by $(-D)$. Therefore, a hyperplane not passing through the origin can be simply represented by $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \dots + a_nx_n =1$ where $a_i = -C_i / D$. A hyperplane always cuts the whole space into two half-spaces, and this simple equation ensures that any point in the same half-space as the origin always makes the inequality $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \dots + a_nx_n <= 1$ hold.

**Question:** Consider a polyhedron $S$ (may be unbounded) formed by $m$ hyper planes not passing through the origin. We assume that $m>n$ throughout the question since $S$ cannot be bounded when $m \le n$.

$$S := \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} <= \mathbf{b}\},$$

where

$$\mathbf{A} :=  [a_{11}, a_{12}, \dots , a_{1n}; \\ a_{21}, a_{22}, \dots , a_{2n}; \\ \dots ; \\a_{m1}, a_{m2}, \dots , a_{mn};] $$

is a $m$ by $n$ matrix and $\mathbf{b} := [1;1;...;1] \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I am wondering which constraints on the coefficients $\mathbf{A}$ can guarantee that the polyhedron $S$ is a bounded polytope? (Of course $S$ is nonempty. The origin $ \in S$ because $a_{k1}0 + a_{k2}0 + \dots +a_{kn}0 = 0 <= 1, k \in \{1,...,m\}$).

Comment: Show that it $S$ is bounded **iff** $\ker A$ is trivial.

Comment: @copper.hat would you mind giving a detailed explanation or rationale, thx.

Comment: You need to do some work. One direction is immediate.

Comment: My apologies, my statement above is incorrect. $A$ can be injective without the set being unbounded. Just take the identity, for example.

Comment: @copper.hat So no good answers yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the best I can figure for the moment is that $S$ is unbounded **iff** there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax \le 0 $ (or $\ge 0$, of course). But this is not of much help.

Comment: I added a somewhat unsatisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: $S$ is unbounded **iff** there is some $x\neq 0$ satisfying $Ax \le 0$.

Suppose $S$ is unbounded, then there are $x_n \in S$ such that $\|x_n\| \to \infty$, and $A {x_n \over \|x_n\|} \le {b \over \|x_n\|}$. A compactness/continuity argument shows that some unit $x$ exists that satisfies $Ax \le 0$. For the other direction, suppose $x\neq 0$ satisfies $Ax \le 0$, then clearly $nx \in S$ for all $n$.

Note that the existence of a non zero $x$ satisfying $Ax \le 0$ is equivalent to the existence of a non zero $x$ satisfying $Ax \ge 0$, so to avoid confusing myself I will address the latter.

Let $Q= \{ x | x \ge 0 \}$ be the positive quadrant and $\Sigma = \{ x \in Q| \sum_k x_k = 1 \}$.

We are looking for a non zero $x \in {\cal R}A \cap Q$. Since both ${\cal R}A, Q$ are both cones, it is equivalent to determining if ${\cal R}A $ intersects $\Sigma$.

Note that if $\ker A$ is non trivial, then $S$ is clearly unbounded, so I will assume that $\ker A$ is trivial subsequently.

The problem reduces to solving
$\min_{\mu \in \Sigma} \min_x \|Ax-\mu\|$. If we solve the inner least squares problem and let
$B= A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T - I$, the problem becomes
$\min_{\mu \in \Sigma} \|B\mu\|$.

The last problem is equivalent to $\min_{y \in C} \|y\|$, where
$C = \operatorname{co} \{ B e_k \}$.

Hence $S$ is bounded **iff** $\ker A$ is non trivial and $\min_{y \in C} \|y\| > 0$.

Comment: Thx but what are the meanings of $RA$, $co\{\}$, $e_k$?

Comment: ${\cal R} A$ is the range space of $A$, $e_k$ is the $k$th unit vector ($(0,...,0,1,0,...,)$) and $\operatorname{co} \{B e_k \}$ is the convex hull of the points $B e_k $ (the columns of $B$).

Answer (score 0):

I found a python package to do this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827112/how-to-find-vertices-of-a-polytope-in-python

Run

> vertices = pypoman.compute_polytope_vertices(A,b)

If the set $S$ is not bounded, then we get the following error:

raise Exception("Polyhedron is not a polytope") Exception: Polyhedron is not a polytope".

Alternatively, Use pycddlib. If the first column of the output are not all 1, then this means Polyhedron is not bounded.